# mySQL query between two dates issue with sum

Tags: mysql

I have the next table named expenses_partial_payment.

[image]

My query is the next, i need the sum of amount_paid as total_paid:

```
SELECT id_partial_payment, epp.id_billing, epp.id_user, epp.month_of_payment,  
            COALESCE(SUM(epp.amount_paid),0) AS total_paid,
            (be.total - amount_paid) AS pending_total , be.total as total

            FROM expenses_partial_payment epp 
            INNER JOIN BillingExpenses be  ON epp.id_billing = be.id_billing
            WHERE epp.id_user = 23
```

[image]

but when i add in the clause where

```
WHERE epp.id_user = 23 AND  (Month_of_payment BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND LAST_DAY('2016-01-01'))
```

[image]

I have an error with the total_piad, the query returns only the last row (300) and don't sum the amount_paid , the correct sum must be 501.00

What can i do to get the correct sum adding the clause where to filter the month_of_payment

> (month_of_payment BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND LAST_DAY('2016-01-01'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

month_of_payment BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND LAST_DAY('2016-01-01')

last day() returns the last day of the Month not year. So it will not pull up data in the month greater than January.

Comment: Try LAST_DAY('2016-02-01').

Comment: oh, its correct,  i put the incorrect month , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your date with this

```
STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
```